# delete object from document array in mongodb collection using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to remove an element from an array attribute of my object.
This is my schema :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
      type: Number
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    names: [
    {
      text: { type: String, required: true },
      order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true 
      }
    }
   ]
});
```

this is my mongoose function :

```
User.findOne({ userID: Number(req.params.id) })
    .then((user) => {
        user.names.remove({text: "john", order: 3});
          recipe.save(() => {
            res.json(recipe);
          });
    })
```

I don't understand why it's not good :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation of mongoose [remove method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-remove) remove operation is only executed when a callback is passed. To force execution without a callback, you must first call `remove()` and then execute it by using the `exec()` method.

Since you are trying to delete from array of objects then better would be to use pull operator. You don't have to do find and remove, you can simply use update method.

As per documentation of [$pull operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) you can either specify a value or a condition

i.e.

```
{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }
```

In your scenario you need to either specify complete value of one or more **names** item object or an condition that matches one or more **names** item

Add the condition where you match id of names item or if you don't know that then you can use elemMatch to match on few fields i.e.

Use following pull condition to solve the issue:

```
        User.update(
          { _id: Number(req.params.id) },
          { $pull: { 'names':  { $elemMatch: { 'text': "john", 'order': 3 }} } },
          (error, success) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(success);
          }
       );
```

Comment: mongoose with promise no need to use exec(), we can use directly then()

Comment: Just using remove operator without passing callback or with promise(without using then) remove is not executed. In that scenario we have to use exec to execute the query e.g. 

`const query = Model.find().remove({ name: 'Anne Murray' })`

This is not executed as no callback is passed.

Comment: I try this solution but it delete all the names array items ! :/ In my test names = [{text: 'aaa', order: 1}, {text: 'bbb', order: 2}, {text: 'ccc', order: 3}], and I use elemMatch with {order: 2}

Comment: If you specify a single query predicate in the $elemMatch expression, $elemMatch is not necessary. So you could simply specify  { $pull: {  order: 2 } }. The $pull expression applies the condition to each element of the results array as though it were a top-level document. I think it should have worked for you. Can you share what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

To Remove Element from array in document please follow as below

```
User.update(
    {
        userID: Number(req.params.id),

    },
    {
        $pull: { names: { $elemMatch: { text: "john", order: 3 } } }
    },
    {
        multi: false
    }
).lean().then((Status) => {
    console.log("Status-->", Status);
    res.json('Removed Successfully');
})
```

Refer $pull operator at [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Comment: I try this solution too but it delete all the names array items :/ In my test names = [{text: 'aaa', order: 1}, {text: 'bbb', order: 2}, {text: 'ccc', order: 3}], and I use elemMatch with {order: 2}